# How to extract string between 2 xml tags?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, ash

I have a string like this

```
<anytag>my message</anytag>
```

How I can extract the message between the tags with sed or awk?
So I get only `"my message"`

Comment: use xml parsers to manipulate xml data

Comment: I do not want to install xml paser for a lite extract string, my xml message is not complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/<.*>\(.*\)<\/.*>/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using xmllint *(from libxml2)*:

```
xmllint --xpath '//anytag/text()' <(echo "<anytag>my message</anytag>")
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
awk -F'[><]' '{print $3}'   Input_file
```

Making field separator as '[><]' and printing 3rd field.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to install xml paser for a lite extract string, my xml
>   message is not complicated

For simple strings you may use the following ***sed*** approach:

```
s="<anytag>my message</anytag>"
sed 's~<[^<>]*>\([^<>]*\)</[^<>]*>~\1~' <<< $s
```

The output:

```
my message
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` command if each line of your file is in the format you have shown.

```
awk -F "<[^<]+?>" '{print $2;}' <filename>
```

Input:

`<anytag>my message</anytag>
<mytag>abc</mytag>`

Output:

```
my message
abc
```